# Is it code-compliant to attach a patio to the roof like this?

Tags: roof, carpentry, patio, ledger, cover

I want to attach a patio cover to my house. Trouble is the clearance between the window and the roof rafters is too small for a ledger. I was considering the option of attaching to the roof top like this:

[image: x]

[image: x]

Is it ok to attach to the rafters like this to support and distribute the load?

If so, any reinforcement required to the roof skeleton?

Patio size would be ~25x12ft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have pictured is a typical hip detail. As long as you use proper sized lumber for the span and center dimensions it looks fine. The only thing I see is a lack of metal rafter hangers, bird's mouths and collar ties over the open span. Collar ties are not absolutely necessary if a cathedral design is wanted. basically, it looks OK.  Check your local codes in case they have special requirements in hurricane prone or heavy snow load areas.

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn’t be a “code” compliance or non compliance. This would be an “engineering” requirement. This style hip/ ridge is extremely common ie, patio additions and dormers. The question comes up is span vs dimension, bigger span= larger dimensional lumber.

Comment: "Code" compliance depends a lot on the location of the home. Since the OP didn't specify 8 years ago when he asked, it's hard for us to know for certain.